# How do you add a custom field to a Phabricator Differential commit?

Tags: phabricator

`Arc Diff` brings up an editor with a template to describe your branch's changes (summary, test plan, reviewers, etc.) How do I go about adding a field to this template?

I was looking at the [`DifferentialFieldSpecification` class](https://github.com/facebook/phabricator/blob/master/src/applications/differential/field/specification/DifferentialFieldSpecification.php) which looks like it is intended to be subclassed for this very purpose, but I was unsure of where to begin.

Answer (score 1):

You can add simple custom fields using `differential.custom-field-definitions`.

Example:

```js
{
  "companyname:fieldname": {
    "name": "Short Name",
    "description": "",
    "type": "text",
    "caption": "Text to display below the field when editing.",
    "required":false,
    "disabled":false,
    "edit":true
  }
}
```

For more complicated fields, please have a look at the [Phabricator documentation](https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabricator/article/custom_fields/).

Comment: this is no longer available (though they plan on bringing it back)

Comment: @GoodPerson appears to refer to [Phabricator update 2017.02](https://secure.phabricator.com/w/changelog/2017.02/), specifically [T12085](https://secure.phabricator.com/T12085). Though I do not see how this affects the `differential.custom-field-definitions` configuration value, which is [still documented](https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabricator/article/custom_fields/) and to which I could not find anything in the changelog. Even T12085 does not mention any change to it.

Comment: `differential.custom-field-definitions` is no longer supported (as of April 2021). The linked url shows "Add Fields: Planned": https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabricator/article/custom_fields/